# Color Nodes According the Communities when using Girvan Newman Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, nodes, networkx

In the code below, I'd like to color the nodes according to the communities the girvan newman algorithm will give.

```
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
posi_gn = nx.spring_layout(G)
comp = community.girvan_newman(G)
posi_gn = nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw_networkx(G, posi_gn, with_labels=True,  arrows=True, font_color='gray')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what level you want to define communities, ie how many communities you want to define. Knowing that, you can draw the nodes in groups defined by communities:

```
G = nx.path_graph(10)
posi_gn = nx.spring_layout(G)
comp = nx.community.girvan_newman(G)

k = 3   # number of communities
for _ in range(k-1):
    comms = next(comp)

colors = 'rgb'
for nodes, c in zip(comms, colors):
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, posi_gn, nodelist=nodes, node_color=[c], with_labels=True, arrows=True, font_color='gray')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, posi_gn)
```

Check out the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.centrality.girvan_newman.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if the communities are i.e 10 or 20?

Comment: You just change to 10 communities instead of 3. You'll have to add more colors or color using a different method like a colormap. What issue are you having going to 10?

Comment: Each time i will load a new graph, so I'd like colors to be exactly the amount of the tuples that will be generated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. Will adding more colors not help? You could expand the list or use a colormap method using `node_color` and `cmap` parameters.